# Embed aspx web page content into another web pages

Tags: asp.net, gridview, embed

I have built an ASP.NET 2.0 application where I have an aspx page which contains a GridView with some data that I would like to embed into another application, just like you do with YouTube videos. I have never done this before and I have no idea on how to proceed. 
I could use your suggestions on how to do this. Thanks a lot!

**Later Edit :** I managed to embed the whole page using an `iframe`

`"iframe  id="SndIFrame" runat="server" scrolling="auto" width="100%" height="550px"`

and in code behind I set the src attribute

`SndIFrame.Attributes["src"] = "mypage.aspx"`

But now the problem is that I do not want to show the whole page, but only the gridview inside it. Is there a way to do this? And also how should I send the credentials for login as default parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have server-side programming access, you could just copy the HTML portion generated by the gridview into that new webpage and then refresh the page through javascript. Or you could dynamically copy the desired html via javascript and paste into new page. But that won't persist.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to `postback` *this* (embeded) page then you should have to use `Ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

hope i understand what you mean 
see this post this about infinity scroll 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETInfiniteLoading-16f5bdb8
using xmlfile u can change it to datagridview with paging from querystring 
this will embed the data with infinity scroll
then u can use jquery to update the page every min 
using this http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can approach your way by using below link.

You have to make ActiveX and finally you have the  tag. and it will represent your UI.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CreateActiveXDotNet.aspx